# --inlineSourceMap or --sourceMap in tsconfig.json

Tags: typescript, webpack, source-maps

Must I turn on --inlineSourceMap instead --sourceMap in tsconfig.json when I use cheap-module-eval-source-map as devtool in webpack?

Comment: Yes, you need `{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "sourceMap": true
  }
}` in `tsconfig.json`.

Comment: Thank you for answer!

But I don't know what option I need select --inlineSourceMap or just --sourceMap

Answer (score 7):

The option --sourceMap tells the compiler that you want the source map generation.  The next question is if you want them as separate files .js.map or not.

The option --inlineSourceMap will put generated source maps inside your .js file.

There is yet another option --inlineSources. This one will create a separate .js.map file, which will include the original TypeScript source so you don't need to deploy your .ts files under the server.

Comment: Thank you! I will try to reformulate the question :)

I set up webpack for dev and prod environments, in prod mode I use source-map as devtool in webpack config and --sourceMap option in typescript, but in dev mode I use cheap-module-eval-source-map as devtool. cheap-module-eval-source-map will put generated source maps inside .js file, but I still use --sourceMap option in typescript now.

So, my question is: Must I use --inlineSourceMap instead --sourceMap in tsconfig.json for dev mode?

Best wishes!